# PHP OOP abstract classes subclass registration

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

I have an abstract question for you.

**Question:**
How can a subclass that extends an abstract class register itself to the abstract class or another class?

**Problem:**
Guess we have a module master named `ModuleMaster` and maybe someone else writes another modules to handle a specific problem without modifying the master class and named it `ModuleA`. For that reason we want to implement a dynamic loading of problem solutions.

**My idea:**

File: Extensions.php:

```
namespace Project\Extensions;

class Extensions
{
    public function getLoadedModules()
    {
        var_dump(ModuleMaster::LOADED_MODULES);
    }
}
```

File: Modules\ModuleMaster.php:

```
namespace Project\Extensions\Modules;

abtract class ModuleMaster
{
    public const LOADED_MODULES = array();
}
```

File: Modules\ModuleA.php:

```
namespace Project\Extensions\Modules;

class ModuleA extends ModuleMaster
{
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean and can help with that abstract problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange to use. It's probably a better design to have an external registry for your module. But I think you're asking for this:

File: Extensions.php:

```php
namespace Project\Extensions;
use \Project\Extensions\Modules\ModuleMaster;

class Extensions
{
    public function getLoadedModules()
    {
        var_dump(ModuleMaster::getLoadedModules());
    }
}
```

File: Modules\ModuleMaster.php:

```php
namespace Project\Extensions\Modules;

abstract class ModuleMaster
{
        public static function getLoadedModules() {
                $parent = self::class;
                return array_values(array_filter(\get_declared_classes(), function ($class) use ($parent) {
                        return in_array($parent, class_parents($class));
                }));
        }
}
```

File: Modules\ModuleA.php:

```php
namespace Project\Extensions\Modules;
use \Project\Extensions\Modules\ModuleMaster;

class ModuleA extends ModuleMaster
{
}
```

Example use:

```php
$e = new \Project\Extensions\Extensions;
$e->getLoadedModules();
```

Example result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "Project\Extensions\Modules\ModuleA"
}
```

Please note that the code only works if all your class files are included into the context before running `getLoadedModules()`. PHP won't know your class exists if it is not already loaded into the context.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to create a capability in the parent class which is not required or inappropriate in the child class. This is the opposite of inheritance and hence an anti-pattern. Further, even though it might be considered as an extension of reflection, you are trying to put runtime data in a class - that's not what classes are for.

You've also not explained in any way that I can understand *why* you want to do this.

I suspect you really want to implement a factory, strategy or a registry object.